# ImprSimple chat bot written in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, chat, selenium

I'd like to know if I can improve the performance of my recent bot, and maybe some design patterns too.

So far, it's warning a user if it's using some bad words (which are parsed from `bad_words.txt`) and it's entertaining the users by posting jokes from `jokes.txt`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random


def login_to_rst(base_url, username, password):
    xpaths = {
        'usernameTxtField': "//input[@name='auth']",
        'passwordTxtField': "//input[@name='password']",
        'submitButton': "//*[@id='ipsLayout_mainArea']/div/div[2]/div/form/li[5]/div/button"
    }
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.get(base_url)
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['usernameTxtField']).clear()
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['usernameTxtField']).send_keys(username)
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['passwordTxtField']).clear()
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['passwordTxtField']).send_keys(password)
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitButton']).click()
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.get(base_url)


def write_to_chat(chat_url):
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.get(chat_url)

    bad_words = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('bad_words.txt')]

    time.sleep(5)
    message = "Please use a decent language !"
    xpaths = {
        'textArea': "//*[@id='ipsTabs_elChatTabs_chatroom_panel']/div[1]/div[1]/textarea",
        'submitMessage': "//*[@id='ipsTabs_elChatTabs_chatroom_panel']/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/button"
    }

    parsed_messages, rst_messages_list = [], []
    keep_running = True
    while keep_running:
        divs = FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="ipsList_reset cChatContainer"]/li/div')
        for div in divs:
            rst_messages_list = []
            if div.id not in parsed_messages:
                rst_messages_list.append(div.text)
                print(rst_messages_list)
                parsed_messages.append(div.id)

                for unique_message in rst_messages_list:
                    for word in bad_words:
                        if word in unique_message:
                            FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).clear()
                            FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).send_keys(message)
                            FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitMessage']).click()

                    if '/message1' in unique_message or '/Message1' in unique_message:
                        FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).clear()
                        FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).send_keys("text to be sent")
                        FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitMessage']).click()
                    if '/message2' in unique_message or '/Message2' in unique_message:
                        FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).clear()
                        FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).send_keys("2016 © me")
                        FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitMessage']).click()
                    if '/message3' in unique_message:
                        line = random.choice(open('jokes.txt').readlines())
                        FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).clear()
                        FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).send_keys(line)
                        FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitMessage']).click()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FIREFOX_DRIVER = webdriver.Firefox()

    login_to_rst('https://link-login', 'user', 'pass')
    write_to_chat('https://link-final-url')
```

I accept any constructive critiques as long as they are followed by a rational explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `open` when you can. `with` is a keyword for using a context manager, which will automatically ensure that files are always properly closed, which you don't ensure when you just call `open` in a list comprehension.

```
with open('bad_words.txt') as f:
    bad_words = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
```

`keep_running` is always `True`, so why not just use `while True`.

To reduce nesting levels, I'd flip the condition from this:

```
rst_messages_list = []
if div.id not in parsed_messages:
    rst_messages_list.append(div.text)
```

to this

```
rst_messages_list = []
if div.id in parsed_messages:
    continue

rst_messages_list.append(div.text)
```

`continue` moves onto the next iteration, so it is effectively the same as before except that your code isn't as deeply nested.

When testing `unique_message`, you should really make it lowercase for ease of testing. That way you can match regardless of case. Also when you're testing if any word in bad_words is in unique_message, there's a Python function that does that, called `any`:

```
for unique_message in rst_messages_list:
    unique_message = unique_message.lower()
    if any(word in unique_message for word in bad_words):
```

This does the same as you had before, but now the if and for statements are combined in one line. The one main difference, is that your old code would message the user repeatedly if they used multiple bad words, which I assume was not the intention.

You repeatedly call these lines:

```
FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).clear()
FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).send_keys(message)
FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitMessage']).click()
```

Make this a function:

```
def send_message(message, xpaths):
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).clear()
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).send_keys(message)
    FIREFOX_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitMessage']).click()
```

That reduces your code drastically:

```
if any(word in unique_message for word in bad_words):
    send_message(message, xpaths)
elif '/message1' in unique_message:
    send_message("text to be sent", xpaths)
elif '/message2' in unique_message:
    send_message("2016 © me", xpaths)
elif '/message3' in unique_message:
    line = random.choice(open('jokes.txt').readlines())
    send_message(line, xpaths)
```

Worth noting that since these are all `if` commands, you might send every one of these messages, for a message like `"/message1 /message2 /message3 smeg"` (assuming that smeg is on your list of `bad_words`). You should all but the first one `elif`s, so that they're mutually exclusive and only one (or none) will run.

Last point, unless calling `webdriver.Firefox()` is a lot of work for the script, I'd put that at the top instead of in `if __name__ == "__main__"`, as it's easier to spot when it's near the top of the page, after imports. That's the convention for where constants should go.

```
FIREFOX_DRIVER = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: thanks for the tips. They are great. One question though: if the second `if` will become `elif` shouldn't the next `if`s to also become `elif`s? More, in `send_message(message)` method I think you forgot to add the xpaths, right ?

Comment: When you said about `if div.id not in parsed_messages:`, should I have all of those lines or I have to cut off the first 3 ones ?

Comment: @Alex That's what I meant about `elif`s, I wasn't clear though so I edited that.  You're right about `xpaths`. If `xpaths` was a global constant it wouldn't need to be explicitly passed, and it probably should be one. I'm not sure what you mean with that last point, you don't need to remove lines. I just showed a small snippet of how the script would look with that condition, to show the indentation of those lines.

Comment: I was talking about: `To reduce nesting levels, I'd flip the condition from this:` and I was expecting a piece of code after that statement, then something like `to this:` and some other code after. Now, I'm confused because I don't know what to keep in that block ^__^

Comment: @Alex Oh woops. I left out my *"to this"*, is it clearer in the edited version?

Comment: yes, it's clearer. Could you also edit the last part (the one with `if` and `elif`) ? It will be something like: `if condition`, `elif condition`, `elif condition`, `else` ?

Comment: Thanks. One more thing that doesn't seem to work: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'unique_message' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @Alex Did you remove the `for unique_message in rst_messages_list:` line? You still need that to be included.

Comment: Nope, of course I didn't. But I solved the error. I just moved `unique_message = unique_message.lower()` inside the `for loop` and it worked.